# ifelse action depending on document type in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

When preparing reports using `rmarkdown`: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ one may want the document to render differently depending upon the document type.  For instance I may want to embed a youtube video if the document being rendered is an html file where as if it's pdf or MS Word I would want the hyper-linked URL instead.

Is there a way to tell `rmarkdown` something like this:

```
if (html) {
    <iframe width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnblmZdTbYs?    feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
} else {
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekBJgsfKnlw
}
```

**code**

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
library(rmarkdown)
render("foo.Rmd", "all")
```

**foo.Rmd**

```
---
title: "For Fun"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: journal
    number_sections: true
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
  word_document:
    fig_width: 5
    fig_height: 5
    fig_caption: true
---

## Good times

<iframe width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnblmZdTbYs?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can access the output format via `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`. This will return a string with the target output format. Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
```
````

This returns "html" for html_document, "docx" for word_document, and "latex" for pdf_document. So to answer your question you can do something like:

```
html <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html"
```

Comment: Thanks for answerinf.  I should have answered this as I found the answer some time ago: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out [in an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458182/), `knitr` 1.18 [introduced](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-118) the following functions

```
knitr::is_html_output()
knitr::is_latex_output()
```

As the name suggests, `is_html_output()` checks if the output is HTML. You would add something like this to `foo.Rmd`:

````
```{r results='asis'}
if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    cat('<iframe width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnblmZdTbYs?        feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
} else {
    cat("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekBJgsfKnlw")
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using code chunk options.

Get the output file type at the beginning of the document.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
out_type <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
```
````

Then, `eval` the code chunk depending on the file type:

````
```{r, results='asis', eval=(out_type=="html"), echo=FALSE}
cat('<iframe width="640" height="390"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnblmZdTbYs?feature=player_detailpage"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>')
```

```{r, results='asis', eval=(out_type!="html"), echo=FALSE}
cat('https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnblmZdTbYs?feature=player_detailpage')
```
````

Comment: Someone may be able to use a slightly more elegant approach using `{asis ...}` instead of `{r results='asis', ...}`.